# Find the number of relatively compact connected components

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<5\}$ and $K=\{(x,y):1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2 or 3\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$.  Then:

Find the number of relatively compact connected components of $X\setminus K$ in $X$.

I drew a picture of the problem and I found since the boundary i.e $x^2+y^2=1 or x^2+y^2=2$ gets erased in $X\setminus K$ so it has zero connected components .

But the answer given is $2$ .Why?Any help

Answer (score 1):

You have $$X \setminus K = D \cup E \cup F$$ where $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 < 1\}$, $E=\{(x,y): 2 < x^2+y^2 < 3\}$ and $F=\{(x,y): 4 < x^2+y^2 < 5\}$.

$D$, $E$ and $F$ are connected components of $X$. $D$ and $E$ are also relatively compact in $X$. But not $F$.

So the answer is indeed $2$.

Comment: Connected is right but I don't get why they are relatively compact;Can you explain please

Comment: A relatively compact subset is a subset whose closure is compact. What are $D$, $E$ and $F$ closures in $X$?

Comment: then why is $F$ not so

Comment: You ask a new question before answering mine. Please answer my last question.

Comment: Closure of $D$ is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$

Comment: Closure of $E$ is $\{(x,y):2\leq x^+y^2\leq 3\}$ is it right please let me know

Comment: That is right for D and E. F closure in X is $\{(x, y) : 4 \le x^2+y^2 < 5\}$ which is not compact.